# NativeScript detect incoming call

Tags: android, angular, typescript, nativescript

I developed a NativeScript app using a plugin to enable audio playing. Now, if I move the app in background it keeps playing (which is good) but it doesn't stop when the user receives a call. Is it possible to stop it whenever I receive a call or better, whenever the audio output device is busy, such as if I start Spotify or youtube over my app.

Answer (score 0):

Need something like this, not for music purpose though. I am building a application for my company, where i need to look trough our clients and show if it is one of our clients calling. The only thing I've found is this plugin.

https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-call